# Access Denied in some AJAX request on IE?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-domain

These are two requests that I'm trying to fire

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON",
    type : 'POST',
    cache : false,
    dataType : 'json',
    data : {
        username: "demo", 
        north:10, 
        south: 10, 
        east:10, 
        west:10}
}).done(function(data) {
    alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(data));
}).fail(function(a, b, c, d) {
    alert("Failure: " 
          + JSON.stringify(a) + " " 
          + JSON.stringify(b) + " " 
          + JSON.stringify(c) + " " 
          + JSON.stringify(d) );
});
```

and

```
$.ajax({
    url : "https://app.testafy.com/api/v0/user/login",
    type : 'POST',
    cache : false,
    dataType : 'json',
    data : {
        login_name: "abashir", 
        password: "P@ssw0rd"}
}).done(function(data) {
    alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(data));
}).fail(function(a, b, c, d) {
    alert("Failure: " 
          + JSON.stringify(a) + " " 
          + JSON.stringify(b) + " " 
          + JSON.stringify(c) + " " 
          + JSON.stringify(d) );
});
```

Due to crossdomain issues in IE, I found an online solution for ["No Transport" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418290/ajax-post-request-on-ie-fails-with-error-no-transport/15460072#15460072)  which is that I should modify code by adding:

```
if (!jQuery.support.cors && window.XDomainRequest) {
    var httpRegEx = /^https?:\/\//i;
    var getOrPostRegEx = /^get|post$/i;
    var sameSchemeRegEx = new RegExp('^'+location.protocol, 'i');
    var xmlRegEx = /\/xml/i;

    // ajaxTransport exists in jQuery 1.5+
    jQuery.ajaxTransport('text html xml json', function(options, userOptions, jqXHR){
        // XDomainRequests must be: asynchronous, GET or POST methods, HTTP or HTTPS protocol, and same scheme as calling page
        if (options.crossDomain && options.async && getOrPostRegEx.test(options.type) && httpRegEx.test(userOptions.url) && sameSchemeRegEx.test(userOptions.url)) {
            var xdr = null;
            var userType = (userOptions.dataType||'').toLowerCase();
            return {
                send: function(headers, complete){
                    xdr = new XDomainRequest();
                    if (/^\d+$/.test(userOptions.timeout)) {
                        xdr.timeout = userOptions.timeout;
                    }
                    xdr.ontimeout = function(){
                        complete(500, 'timeout');
                    };
                    xdr.onload = function(){
                        var allResponseHeaders = 'Content-Length: ' + xdr.responseText.length + '\r\nContent-Type: ' + xdr.contentType;
                        var status = {
                            code: 200,
                            message: 'success'
                        };
                        var responses = {
                            text: xdr.responseText
                        };

                                try {
                                    if (userType === 'json') {
                                        try {
                                            responses.json = JSON.parse(xdr.responseText);
                                        } catch(e) {
                                            status.code = 500;
                                            status.message = 'parseerror';
                                            //throw 'Invalid JSON: ' + xdr.responseText;
                                        }
                                    } else if ((userType === 'xml') || ((userType !== 'text') && xmlRegEx.test(xdr.contentType))) {
                                        var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
                                        doc.async = false;
                                        try {
                                            doc.loadXML(xdr.responseText);
                                        } catch(e) {
                                            doc = undefined;
                                        }
                                        if (!doc || !doc.documentElement || doc.getElementsByTagName('parsererror').length) {
                                            status.code = 500;
                                            status.message = 'parseerror';
                                            throw 'Invalid XML: ' + xdr.responseText;
                                        }
                                        responses.xml = doc;
                                    }
                                } catch(parseMessage) {
                                    throw parseMessage;
                                } finally {
                                    complete(status.code, status.message, responses, allResponseHeaders);
                                }
                            };
                            xdr.onerror = function(){
                                complete(500, 'error', {
                                    text: xdr.responseText
                                });
                            };
                            xdr.open(options.type, options.url);
                            //xdr.send(userOptions.data);
                            xdr.send();
                        },
                        abort: function(){
                            if (xdr) {
                                xdr.abort();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
};

jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

and adding the following property in ajax request

```
crossDomain: true,
```

So that the final codes are as in those two links:

- http://jsfiddle.net/8vnxA/6/
- http://jsfiddle.net/bjW8t/4/

You may try both of them on IE, you will find that one is working and the other doesn't !!

**The question is: why one of the request returns success and the other still has access denied problem and fails ?!!**

Comment: Both of them seem to work fine for me my friend. The second one just says that the daily limit for the demo has been reached :)

Comment: Did you try both of them on IE9 ?

Comment: have you tried changing your datatype to "jsonp"?

Comment: Yup, it didn't help too.

Comment: Changing to jsonp didn't help me either.