# .done not working while .fail works in IE9, works fine with chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making an ajax call and IE9 is not working for .done, however I am getting error message from .fail. 
This code works perfectly fine for chrome and IE 11.

I have looked around a lot and spend good time on stackoverflow to find the solution. I have tried various different options.

Main thing which I am unable to understand that .done() seems to not working, while I get the error message on .error() or .fail().

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"/>
  <title>Zip Lookup</title>
  <link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://spider/css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" />
  <link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://spider/css/3CLStyle.css" />
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/ccclogicjavascripts/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">



  function Zip_Lookup(param, fieldkey) {
      //alert(param);
      $.ajax({
          url: 'http://spider/webservices/ClinkUtilities/ziplookup.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: "application/json",
          contents: "application/json",
          type: 'get',
          data: param
      })
        .done(function (data) {
            //.done(function (data) {
            alert("done");
            // if you don't do this multiple passes through the control will generate dupes in the list
            ZipResult.length = 0
            if (!isObjectEmpty(data)) {
                //if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)) {
                //if (JSON.stringify(data) !== '[]') {
                BuildArray(data, ZipResult);
                // if multiple cities need to display and select here
                if (ZipResult.length > 1) {
                    var html = "<option value=''>Select City</option>";
                    document.getElementById('zip-dialog-select').options.length = 0;

                    for (var i = 0; i < ZipResult.length; i++) {
                        html += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + ZipResult[i].city + "</option>";
                    }
                    $('#zip-dialog-select').append(html);
                    $("#zip-dialog").dialog("open");
                } else {
                    ZipDialogCallback(0);
                }
            } else {
                alert('Zip not found - manually enter city and state');
            }
        })
      .fail(function (data) {
          alert('Zip Lookup failed!');
      });
  }
```

Comment: How about outputting the arguments of the fail function, and telling us what they say ?

Comment: it returns [object Object], is it has do something with json?

Comment: after stringify it gives me {"readyState":0, "status":0, "statusText":"No Transport"}

Comment: solved using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418290/ajax-post-request-on-ie-fails-with-error-no-transport