# jquery ajax call is not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having some trouble with the code below. It will not run in IE9. It works fine in other browsers though. 
I have placed an alert inside the code but that piece of code is not reached.
anyone has got any idea how to solve this issue?

```
 NWF$.ajax({
 url: 'http://pdfservice/training/',
 data: JSON.stringify(dataJSON),
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 dataType: 'json',
 type: 'POST',
 cache: false,
 success: function (fileName) {
  alert('ok!');
            window.location.href = 'http://pdfservice/training/?meeting=' + fileName;
 },
 error: function (result) {
 alert(JSON.stringify(result));
        }
 });
```

I just changed the fail to error and this is the error that I get:

```
{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"No Transport"}
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception inside your console?

Comment: Which version of jquery?

Comment: It is jquery used by Nintex and I think it is using 1.10.1 version of jquery.

Comment: No I don't see any exception in the console

Comment: Try after removing `dataType`

Comment: I removed it by I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery w Ajax for IE9 is broken.

This is supported through a [jquery plugin](https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest)

"Implements automatic Cross Origin Resource Sharing support using the XDomainRequest object for IE8 and IE9 when using the $.ajax function in jQuery 1.5+."

Comment: I included jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js in my page but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your JSON data is corrupt.

Fix your JSON data, you can use [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com) to validate your JSON response to make sure it's valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, figured I'd add my findings from [AJAX POST request on IE fails with error "No Transport"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418290/ajax-post-request-on-ie-fails-with-error-no-transport)

**I'm adding the code in the event it gets deleted:**

```
if (!jQuery.support.cors && window.XDomainRequest) {
    var httpRegEx = /^https?:\/\//i;
    var getOrPostRegEx = /^get|post$/i;
    var sameSchemeRegEx = new RegExp('^'+location.protocol, 'i');
    var xmlRegEx = /\/xml/i;

    // ajaxTransport exists in jQuery 1.5+
    jQuery.ajaxTransport('text html xml json', function(options, userOptions, jqXHR){
        // XDomainRequests must be: asynchronous, GET or POST methods, HTTP or HTTPS protocol, and same scheme as calling page
        if (options.crossDomain && options.async && getOrPostRegEx.test(options.type) && httpRegEx.test(userOptions.url) && sameSchemeRegEx.test(userOptions.url)) {
            var xdr = null;
            var userType = (userOptions.dataType||'').toLowerCase();
            return {
                send: function(headers, complete){
                    xdr = new XDomainRequest();
                    if (/^\d+$/.test(userOptions.timeout)) {
                        xdr.timeout = userOptions.timeout;
                    }
                    xdr.ontimeout = function(){
                        complete(500, 'timeout');
                    };
                    xdr.onload = function(){
                        var allResponseHeaders = 'Content-Length: ' + xdr.responseText.length + '\r\nContent-Type: ' + xdr.contentType;
                        var status = {
                            code: 200,
                            message: 'success'
                        };
                        var responses = {
                            text: xdr.responseText
                        };

                                try {
                                    if (userType === 'json') {
                                        try {
                                            responses.json = JSON.parse(xdr.responseText);
                                        } catch(e) {
                                            status.code = 500;
                                            status.message = 'parseerror';
                                            //throw 'Invalid JSON: ' + xdr.responseText;
                                        }
                                    } else if ((userType === 'xml') || ((userType !== 'text') && xmlRegEx.test(xdr.contentType))) {
                                        var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
                                        doc.async = false;
                                        try {
                                            doc.loadXML(xdr.responseText);
                                        } catch(e) {
                                            doc = undefined;
                                        }
                                        if (!doc || !doc.documentElement || doc.getElementsByTagName('parsererror').length) {
                                            status.code = 500;
                                            status.message = 'parseerror';
                                            throw 'Invalid XML: ' + xdr.responseText;
                                        }
                                        responses.xml = doc;
                                    }
                                } catch(parseMessage) {
                                    throw parseMessage;
                                } finally {
                                    complete(status.code, status.message, responses, allResponseHeaders);
                                }
                            };
                            xdr.onerror = function(){
                                complete(500, 'error', {
                                    text: xdr.responseText
                                });
                            };
                            xdr.open(options.type, options.url);
                            //xdr.send(userOptions.data);
                            xdr.send();
                        },
                        abort: function(){
                            if (xdr) {
                                xdr.abort();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
    };

jQuery.support.cors = true;
```